# WSO2 : Where can i find a good Web services Policy documentation

Tags: web-services, wso2, policy

**I need to use web service policy**

To create SLA for services i found(thought) that should be use ws policy and place it into wsdl file. but i dont how to do it?!

Where can i found a good documentation for do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access them in the services dashboard.

Please refer this documentation link too.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/WS-Policy+Implementation

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you dear Shelan Perera . i'm confused, i dont know where should i start?! please guide me.

Comment: thank you dear Shelan Perera . i'm confused, i dont know where should i start?! please guide me. i want to add custom information to service description, for example Response Time of service that client can access to it. what is your recommendation? should be learn meta data exchange at first and ws-policy after that?i need update document for improve my knowledge in this issue. i'm beginner withi this topics.i'm Msc student and have to implement it in my project, i'm not a programmer in componey. please guide me dear!

Comment: You can have a look at this paper http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221001839_Enhancing_web_service_selection_by_QoS-based_ontology_and_WS-policy. Further i think you may be interested in http://wsag4j.sourceforge.net/site/. I have not evaluated this and i answered previously thinking that you need to define policies. But those links should guide you in a proper path.

Comment: Dear Perera, thank you for your help. i'm reading wsag4j but i have a question! can i use wsag4j in wso2? i couldn't found any results of wsag4j and wso2 words together by searching in google!!